# Is there a way to use javascript variable inside Laravel blade template?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I  will automatically create the rows of a table in jQuery . by clicking addRow button , function addRow() will do it like below:

```
function addRow(){

  var rowCount = $("table tr").length - 1; 
  var row = '<tr><td><input name=“item[‘+ (rowCount+1) + ']" type="text" value="{{ old(‘item') }}”> @if ($errors->has(‘item’)){{ $errors->first(‘item’) }}@endif<td></tr>' ;

 $("table").append(row);

}
```

I will call this method 5 times and it will create 5 input areas which name are item1. item2, item3, item4, item5.

in server side ,I use Laravel 5.2 Form Request Validation to validate every input field.

But if the validation failed , the old input and error will not set to the correct input field because

I can’t put the javascript variable rowCount into  "{{ old(‘item') }}” which is a blade template.
and the same is {{ $errors->first(‘item’) }}.

I tried to write like this

```
'value="{{ old('giftValue[' . $rowCount .']') }}">'
```

and this

```
'value="{{ old('giftValue[' + $rowCount +’]’) }}">'
```

but does’t work.

does anyone have a good idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: your ending `<td>` tag is not correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one that answered my question, but 
no answer can solve the problem of both the Old Value and the validation Error.

Eventually, I write the JS code  and I also write a server side code which is almost the  same as the JS.
As Mina Abadir said, I should not add server side code to JS.

if the validation failed, I only rendered the Old value and the validation Error in the server side code , in this way ,the most difficult part is that I have to use `Validator::make` to add every error to a `variable($items[$key]['oldvalue'] and $items[$key]['error'])`, which will be displayed in the server-side code .

the server side code like :

```
@if(validation_failed) {
     <input name="item[{{ $key }}]" type="text" value="{{ $items[$key]['oldvalue'] }}">
     @if (!empty($items[$key]['error']))<p class="formTable_error">{{ $items[$key]['error'] }}</p>@endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a Ajax call to route and display using javascript. Something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
              url: '/get-rows',
              data: { code: code }
            })
            .done(function(res) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(res);
                console.log(response);
                 var $id = $('<input type=hidden name=id />').val(res.id);
                 var $email = $('<input type=hidden name=email />').val(res.email);

            $('form[name="rows"]').append($id).append($email).submit();
            })
            .fail(function(err) {
              console.log('Error: ' + err.status);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create the inputs as input array:

```
function addRow(){    
  var rowCount = $("table tr").length - 1; 
  var row = '<tr><td><input name=“items[]" type="text"></td></tr>';

  $("table").append(row);   
}
```

This can be easily validated in the back-end. And you should not add server side code to JS, as it won't work.

In your view, check if the `old` value exists, and hence run a loop to add the `items` back.

```
@if(old('items'))
    @for($i=0;$i<=count(old('items'));$i++)
        <tr><td><input name=“items[]" type="text" value="old('items')[$i]"></td></tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right Approach, but you can try storing the errors and oldInputs in a variable and use it.

Example below:

```
function addRow(){

  var errors = {
    item1:{{$errors->first('item1')}},
    item2:{{$errors->first('item2')}},
    item3:{{$errors->first('item3')}},
    item4:{{$errors->first('item4')}},
    item5:{{$errors->first('item5')}}
  }
  var rowCount = $("table tr").length - 1; 
  var row = '<tr>
                <td>
                    <input name=“item[‘+ (rowCount+1) + ']" type="text" value="{{ old(‘item') }}”> 
                    '+errors["item"+(rowCount+1)]+'
                </td>
            </tr>' ;

 $("table").append(row);

}
```