# laravel blade cannot use the script variable in the markup

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project, i wanna use the script variable in the blade markup but cannot work.
here is the markup:

```
<x-input type="date" id="end_date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}" min="{{effective_date}}"> </x-input>
```

here is the script:

```
<script>
var effective_date;
effective_date = '2023-11-08';
</script>
```

current result is that:

```
Undefined constant \"effective_date\"
```

can you please help me to figure it out? Many THX!

Comment: Blade/PHP is rendered on the server, JS on the client. Why not use a Blade/PHP variable and also use that in JS?

Comment: @brombeer sry I am quite new to laravel, can you please write an example? that would help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a chapter on [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: @brombeer really thanks for your help, but I cannot modify my api, is there anyway that i can use the script variable directly?thanks!

Comment: You can use your JS variable inside JS (obviously). If you want to use your JS variable in PHP you'd need to make an [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) request to an endpoint, do whatever you need to do with that variable in PHP and return the result back to JS

Comment: You might be able to set the `min` attribute of your input via JS (get the element with id `end_date`, set its `min` attribute) and not via Blade (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611774/how-to-change-max-or-min-value-of-input-type-date-from-js might help if you skip the "onchange" part)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use javascript variable inside Laravel blade template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076669/is-there-a-way-to-use-javascript-variable-inside-laravel-blade-template)

Comment: @Adi that also helps me. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

I referred to this question: [How to change max or min value of input type date from JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611774/how-to-change-max-or-min-value-of-input-type-date-from-js)
and adapt the solution to my question, here is my markup:

```
 <x-input type="date" id="end_date" value="{{ date('Y-m-d') }}" > </x-input>
```

here is the script:

```
 var input = document.getElementById("end_date");
 input.min=my_expected_date;
```

then the my_expected_date can used in the markup. I would be happy if this could help you.